# Alternative conditions for Liquifactive Necrosis

Tags: brain, death

A person is beaten on the head hard enough to swell the whole front part of the head. The body is thrown into the river and recovered after about 36 hours. Is this condition enough for liquifactive necrosis to occur? If not, what could have caused it?

Comment: Damn that's an image... Lemme check it out actually...